# How do I prevent a char pointer buffer overflow?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, reference

i.e. -

```
int function(char* txt)
{
   sprintf(txt, "select * from %s;", table);
   //How do I set last char in buffer to NULL here?
}
```

so if the text in table some how was 500 chars long and txt in the main was only defined as 100....

thanks.

Comment: I hope the text in the table doesn't come form Bobby Tables

Comment: NUL is the '\0' character, NULL is a pointer that is uninitialised.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to

- add a parameter to the function that gives the size of the buffer
- use `snprintf()` instead of `sprintf()`
- check the return value of `snprintf()` to see how large the buffer needed to be to hold all the formatted data; if this is larger than or equal to the size of the buffer, you should handle that as you see fit (the buffer will still be null-terminated, but the contents will be truncated to fit; whether this is okay or an error depends entirely on your use case)

(and your function needs a return type...)

Comment: Thanks, I was not sure if there was any other way.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use snprintf to limit the amount of the buffer that is used.

```
function(char* txt, size_t length)
{
   int rv;
   rv = snprintf(txt, length, "select * from %s;", table);
   //How do I set last char in buffer to NULL here?
   if (rv >= length) {
       // error
   }
}
```

Comment: You do need to check the return value of `snprintf()` though - truncation in case is clearly an error that needs to be handled.

Answer (score 0):

About the only thing you can do is malloc enough memory, format the string into that memory, and return a pointer to it. The calling function would then be responsible for freeing the memory when done with it.

Comment: You can do a lot more than that.